# Splicing a lightning cable?

Tags: usb, lightning

I need to connect a female end of a lightning to the male end of a mini USB. I have found one online, but its out of stock. How would I go about splicing these together? Would it work? Just match the wires together?

Answer (score 6):

Unlikely as lightning cables have circuitry in them.

If you are just replacing the USB end of the cable it MIGHT work, but it would depend on what kind of circuitry is in the cable and where it is located.

If there is anything beyond a bog-standard USB on one end then probably not, if one end IS just USB then this might work.

If you do it post back to this question with your results.

Comment: Im trying to understand what you're saying, but im getting lost.

It has to work somehow, because it has been done here http://www.miniinthebox.com/lightning-female-to-mini-usb-male-short-cable-14cm_p693552.html?currency=USD&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&gclid=CPHJgP-_obwCFUUV7AodOH0A1Q

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your application for this type of cable?

Comment: Splicing cables together is very different than buying a cable that does the task outlined. As @steve chambers it is an active cable with circuity in it. The cable you linked to likely has circuits to transform Lightning to USB. That is very different than just connecting cables. Plugging in two cables in an AC electrical outlet and then putting on a DC style connector does not mean that DC will come out, there needs to be circuits.

Comment: @BradfordBenn +1 for 'Plugging in two cables in an AC electrical outlet and then putting on a DC style connector does not mean that DC will come out' - made me chuckle.

Comment: I'm months late for this, but it made me chuckle too. "I put a 3-pin 240v plug on the other end of my guitar cable... when I woke up..."